# How to use VB.net to control Chrome to load more Youtube result?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use VB.net to control Chrome.

When I go to Youtube, I do a search, I see many videos.

In the past, there was a button to go the next page.

Now you will "load more" if youtube page reaches its end.

How I can use VB to control "load more"?

Thanks

Comment: Best option is building a Chrome extension, and VB is not a supported language for this.

Comment: Probably not best to use VB.NET because integrating with Chrome's browser API is hard. You might be able to use Selenium's .NET bindings, but something like this should be a Chrome Extension written in JavaScript or TypeScript.